# Clearing off :target CSS psuedo class

Tags: javascript, html, css, pseudo-class

Lately I've been working on [Shower HTML5+CSS3 presentation template](https://github.com/pepelsbey/shower) to make a upcoming presentation. Shower uses the [CSS `:target` pseudo-class](http://css-tricks.com/on-target/) which makes it easy to identify the current slide in the overview of the slides.

I understand how `:target` works through the hash in the URL, but however I cannot get it to clear the `:target` CSS from all elements at all.

So my question is: given that after an element has been `:target`ed, how can we clear all the `:target` and revert it to the norm using JavaScript? The use of History API doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I previously tried the following two statements and it didn't work (at least on Firefox):

```
history.pushState({}, 'null', window.location.pathname);
window.location.href.substr(0, window.location.href.indexOf('#'));
```

The trick is to use this instead:

```
window.location.hash = '';
```

The problem only exists if we're trying to clear the `:target` selection through JavaScript. Anchor tags with non-existing or empty hashes works: http://jsfiddle.net/SMbsb/3/

Comment: That is so strange (the fact that setting it with the History API doesn't work).

Comment: @BoltClock Are you able to replicate the History API problem? I can't get it to work at all.

Comment: I haven't tried it. I'm not familiar with any new HTML5 APIs.

Answer (score 0):

To clear the hash target with a link without using Javascript, you can just make another `<a>` tag with `href="#"`.

Simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/Y5XB7/
Click on the top black square for the `:target` to be active, then click on the bottom black square to clear it.

```
<a href="#" ...> ... </a>
```