# How to clear a :target choice?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors, target

I have links using the `:target` selector. When clicked, the correspondent paragraph is highlighted. The problem is: once clicked, there is no way to clear the selections. **I wish it to be unchecked when I click again on the selected item.**

*e.g.: if the link 1 is selected and I click again on it, then it becomes unselected.*

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/takddkv9/)

```css
body {
  background: #fefefe;  
}

:target {
   background-color: #ccff66;
}
```

```html
<a href="#link1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#link2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#link3">Link 3</a>
<a href="#link4">Link 4</a>

<p id="link1">This is a text A</p>
<p id="link2">This is a text B</p>
<p id="link3">This is a text C</p>
<p id="link4">This is a text D</p>
```

#### Notes

- *I got success in workarounds with radio/checkboxes instead but I want to know if is possible to achieve this behavior using `:target`.*
- ***it isn't a duplicate:** It's very clear on the post the goal here is to uncheck an item with a second click on it, not with a click on a 3rd "eraser" item (which doesn't even exists on the current scenario).*

Comment: Is javascript an option, because it'll be most common sense way to accomplish this.

Comment: `:target` will make the page to *jump* if you have large block of content, just to check if you're aware of that.

Comment: **@Goose** Javascript is an option yes. Of course the preference is always for the simpler solutions in order pureCSS > javascript > jQuery. **@Pangloss** I am aware of it I noticed this behavior first on the short snippet here and later on css-tricks website; thanks for the warning anyway.

Comment: I would suggest to tag it as javascript too, feel like it's the only way.

Comment: tags updated thanks for the suggestion;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clearing off :target CSS psuedo class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12906509/clearing-off-target-css-psuedo-class)

Comment: both answers there works with a click on a 3rd element to clear the selections; that's not the objective here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, this will do what you want, but I'm not sure it's the wisest thing to do from a semantic point of view. The `:target` selector is meant to be used to style the element whose id matches the hash/fragment in the URL. The code below removes that hash if you click on a link whose hash matches that fragment. However, it's going against what `<a href="#hash">a</a>` is "supposed" to do, which is to take you to the location of the element with the id of "hash". So, use with caution.

```js
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0, z = anchors.length; i < z; i++) {
  var anchor = anchors[i];
  anchor.onclick = function (e) {
    if (e.target.hash === location.hash) {
      location.hash = '';
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  };
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #fefefe;  
}

:target {
   background-color: #ccff66;
}
```

```html
<a href="#link1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#link2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#link3">Link 3</a>
<a href="#link4">Link 4</a>

<p id="link1">This is a text A</p>
<p id="link2">This is a text B</p>
<p id="link3">This is a text C</p>
<p id="link4">This is a text D</p>
```

Comment: **1**- Thanks for the answer. **2**- Can you, please, tell me why it isn't working [**on this scenario**](http://jsfiddle.net/y31bq2wq/1/)?

Comment: @freestock.tk you want `e.currentTarget.hash` instead of `e.target.hash` it happens because you click on the img, not directly on the a element.

Answer (score 5):

You can't really toggle the target on and off with a singe link, but (as a pure CSS workaround) you could use both a `show` and `hide` link and always show only one of them :

```css
.hide, .show, .list {
    padding: 10px;
    display:block;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.list,
.show,
.hide:target {
     display: none;
}

.hide:target + .show,
.hide:target ~ .list {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
  <div>
    <a href="#hide" class="hide" id="hide">Show menu</a>
    <a href="#show" class="show" id="show">Hide menu</a>
    <div  id="drop" class="list">
        <ul>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```